# Fetch month and day value from date attribute of table in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have created a table as below.

```
actor(id, first_name, last_name, dob);
```

Where dob is in Y-m-d format. So I would like to fetch actors, who they have b'days for perticluar month or perticcular day. Please help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query for date

`select * from actor where DAY(dob) = 12;`

And for month

`select * from actor where MONTH(dob) = 5;`

You can combine both of them as well using `AND` operator.

Have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month). You will find more date and time functions that you can use

Answer (score 0):

Try `day` and `month` functions

```
select * from actor
where day(dob)=x and month(dob)=y
```

See more `datetime` functions here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: How to use those function day and month in cakephp?